# I'm getting index.ts:36 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element is not attached to a Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, screenshot

I am trying to screenshot and download it to server, but I am still getting
an error. It's using Wordpress by the way.

> Uncaught (in promise) Provided element is not within a Document

jQuery:

```js
<script>
$('#save').click(function(){
    html2canvas($('#capture'),
    {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');

        a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
        a.download = 'somefilename.jpg';
        a.click();
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please see. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197341/4903314

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the element `a` once it has been created.

```
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

After creating the element, the `a` tag is not found on the document when you trigger `a.click()` because you are not appending it anywhere.